# Pass UIImage to Cell of another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass the content of a `UIImage()` variable to the Cell of the next View Controller.

Basically my layout looks like this:

An image is loaded in ControllerA and then saved in a model.

In the next controller, a TableViewCell is loaded.

I want the picture to load inside the cell.

How do I achieve this?

My code:

First part:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Save the poem.
    savePoem()
}

func savePoem() {
    // Save the poem current completion date.
    poem.date = NSDate()

    // Save the theme name for the poem.
    poem.theme = theme.name

    // Save the currently displayed picture.
    poem.image = ImageView.image

    poem.words = textField.words

    // Make the poem object persist.
    PoemPersistence.sharedInstance.persistPoem(poem)
}
```

The cell loads the pic:

```
func configureWithPoem(poem: Poem) {
    themeLabel.text = "#\(poem.theme)"
    poemLabel.text = poem.words
    pictureImageView.image = poem.image
}

func capturePoemImage() -> UIImage {
    // Hide the share button.
    shareButton.hidden = true

    // Capture a PNG of the view.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, 0)
    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let containerViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Show the share button.
    shareButton.hidden = false

    return containerViewImage
}
```

cell gets loaded in second controller:

```
func poemCellWantsToSharePoem(poemCell: PoemCell) {
    // Find the poem displayed at this index path.
    let indexPath = tableView.mp_indexPathForCell(poemCell)
    let poem = poems[indexPath.row]

    // Generate the image of the poem.
    let poemImage = poemCell.capturePoemImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just you use prepareForSegue() to send data to the next UIViewController 
- Create the segue to next controller (control + Drag), then give the identifier a name.

- Now set up  your destination controller by declaring

  ```
   @IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!
      var image:String ?
  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
     imageView.image = image    
  }
  ```

  this image variable will receive data then assigned it to the @IBOutlet.

  ```
   func prepareForSegue (segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) 
    {

           if  segue.identifier ==   "NAMEOFSEGUEIDENTIFIER"
          {
              let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NAMEOFTHEDESTIONCONTROLLER
              let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        // now the data structure that contains your information, use it there
              let data = dataContainer[indexPath.row]

         // i noticed that you might be using struct so 
         // let's passed the picture from that specific row to the next conroller 
         destinationController.image = data.image
         } 
    }
  ```

I hope that helps :)